# Typeorm - Find entries by ManyToMany relation

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using Nestjs with Typeorm and Mysql, and I can't figure out a good way to filter entries by their many to many relation.

I have these 2 entities:

**Group Entity:**

```js
@Entity({ name: 'groups' })
export class Group {
    @ManyToMany(() => Tag, { eager: true })
    @JoinTable()
    tags: Tag[];
}
```

**Tag Entity**

```js
@Entity({ name: 'tags' })
export class Tag {
    @Column()
    @Index({ unique: true })
    tag?: string;
}
```

And would like to search all groups that have a tag with a specific text.

ie. all groups that have the `tag.tag` "sport"

Tried this code:

```js
const args = {
    where: [
        {
            'tags': In([Like(`%sport%`)]),
        }
    ],
    relations: ['tags'], // TAGS
    take: filter.take,
    skip: filter.skip,
    order: filter.order
};

return super.findAll(args);
```

but it doesn't seem to work..

any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

```
return find({
  where: {
    tags: {
      tag: Like(`%sport%`),
    },
  },
  relations: ['tags'],
});
```

Almost, typeorm accepts an ObjectLiteral or keyof typeof Tags from relations like so:

```
FindConditions<T>: {
  where: {
    [s: keyof typeof T]: any,
  },
}
```

That's not quite it but that's the general gist. And if the `keyof T` is a relation then `any` is replaced with `keyof relation` pretty much anyway.

This is the full type for findConditions https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/find-options/FindConditions.ts

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately, now I am getting this error: 

`QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Group.groupsId' in 'where clause`

I am guessing its related to the way I built the entities? I don't have any reference of group in tag entity (in purpose).

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't synced your database with your entity schema